# S3 Life Cycle rules and Delete marker: why is this delete marker not deleted by s3 life cycle management?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

recently I'm curious about aws s3 lifecycle management and something is not clear for me about **delete marker**.

If I understand correctly, a **delete marker** is created by s3 on a versioning-enabled bucket and an object is deleted specifically, in order to be restored later, since the bucket is versioned.

Also a **delete maker** is considered the **current** version of the deleted object and storage class is standard.

so far so good.

now I try to delete permanently the delete marker with life cycle but after several days I still see some **delete marker** and I don't know what is wrong or what I can do to delete them via life cycle rules.

This is the delete marker I want to delete permanently and it is from last year. The version id is **null**, it means that this object has been put to bucket when the bucket was versioning-enabled, then versioning had been suspended and the object was deleted later, so a delete marker with id Null is created.(I don't remember the actions, but I hope my understand is correct)

[image]

Followings are the configuration of the bucket and the life cycle rules. I suspend the versioning and I check specifically the option to delete **expired object delete marker**.

An **expired object delete marker**, for my understanding, is the object that's been deleted without non-current version created before, or all non-current version have already been deleted.
[image]
[image]